# Findind Prime Numbers - my code does not work

Tags: java, primes

I have this code which I want to use to find prime numbers:

```
public class Primzahlen {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        for(int i = 1;i<100;i++) {
            for(int j=1;j<i;j++) {
                if(i%j == 0) {break;}
                if(j== (i-1)) {System.out.println(i);}  
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

But if I try to run the program the output is empty.

Comment: have you debugged your program?

Comment: @Stultuske it compiles

Comment: Anything `%1` is zero. You could find this by stepping through with a debugger.

Comment: Rephrase: have you set a breakpoint and have you then stepped through the code statement by statement and looked at what each variables is, if that is expected, etc.!?

Comment: Debugger won't help you if the code doesn't compile. It let's you see what is going on when you run it.

Comment: Consider what 2 % 1 is equal to. However, you should do at least a minimal attempt at debugging before posting a question here.

Comment: @New2Math debugging and compiling are two different things. debugging is checking running code, at execution time, step by step, to see what is happening

Comment: @AndyTurner  *Anything %1 is zero.*  Not completely true.  `2.34 % 1 == .34`

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is this that, `j` start from 1 and every number satisfies `i%j` and the loop breaks so `j` should start from 2. I would recommend this code which is more effective and runs in O(sqrt(n)) time :

```
public class Primzahlen {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        for(int i = 2;i<100;i++) {
            for(int j=2;  j < ((int)Math.sqrt(i))+2  ; j++) {
                if(i%j == 0) {break;}
                if(j== ((int)Math.sqrt(i))+1) {System.out.println(i);}
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Isn't it something like n*log(n)?

Comment: @NtFreX I mean for one particular number.

Comment: the only problem is that it does not show that 2 is a prime number

Comment: also 99 is not included

Comment: `j*j <= i` is a far easier inner loop condition. Consequently, `(j+1)*(j+1) > i` is an easier printing condition.

Comment: @New2Math 99 is not prime (99= 3*33)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions.

- Seed the first prime as 2.  Since 2 is the only even prime this allows subsequent candidates to be just the odd numbers.  So starting with 3, increment the candidates by 2.
- Only check the primes up to the square root of the candidate.
- Since you are finding primes, use the ones already found as the divisors to test for primality.  Say the candidate is 17.  Primes 2,3,5,7,11,13 have already been found.  By applying the previous square root rule, all you need to do is see if 17 is divisible by 3, or 5, and not 2 thru 16.  If it were divisible by any prime greater than its square root, it would have already been detected.

For a completely different approach, check out [The Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).